# How do you access certain parts of an array with type []interface{} in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, maps

I have a map with string keys and different types for values, when printing it looks like this:

```
map[command:ls count:[1 1]]
```

When checking `reflect.TypeOf` on the count it returns type `[]interface{}`. I cannot access the values by index, and if I try passing it into a function that accept a param of type `[]interface{}` it claims that I'm tying to pass a value of type `interface{}`

I would like to access the count in this example which would be 2 values. `1` and `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to differentiate type and underlying type. Your map is of the type `map[string]interface{}`. Which means that the value for `count` is of type `interface{}`, and its underlying type if `[]interface{}`. So you can't pass the count as a type `[]interface{}`. You have do a type assertion it before using it as an array. Every item will then of type `interface{}`, which can in turn be asserted as `int` (as it seem your data is).

Example:

```
count := m["count"].([]interface{})
value1 := count[0].(int)
value2 := count[1].(int)
```

Comment: Thank you, you've explained this incredibly well and your solution works perfectly.